# Convex combination of iid Bernoulli random variables

Tags: probability

I'm looking for a lower bound for the probability that an arbitrary convex combination of iid Bernoulli (p) random variables is at least p. My guess is p/2, but I'm happy with any positive lower bound that depends only on p.

For example, if p is slightly above 1/2, and the convex combination is simply the average of two variables, then the probability is slightly above 1/4.

Comment: This is cross-posted on MO and has an answer: https://mathoverflow.net/q/278117/14319